# Comparing normally distributed variables

Tags: pr.probability, algorithms

Given two normally distributed variables `x_1, x_2`, is there a non-simulation method of calculating the probability that `x_1 > x_2`?

Generalizing a bit, what is the probability that given a list of normally distributed variables `x_i`, the probability that `x_a = max x_i`?

Comment: I assume that you mean *joint* normal, in which case x_1-x_2 is normal. The second qu. asks if the set of joint normal rv's x_a-x_i are all positive, which is more difficult (requires some numerical integration, I think).

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do it via numerical integration, but was hoping there's something simple I'm missing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For normal random variables, the probability P(X > Y) can be calculated in closed form. See this post on [random inequalities](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/07/26/random-inequalities-ii-analytical-results/).

Regarding your more general question, see this article on random inequalities with [three or more random variables](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/09/06/random-inequalities-vii-three-or-more-variables/).

Comment: Thanks, I don't have enough rep to upvote you, but I will look into this.